# HttpEntity alternate in android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, multipartform-data, android-networking

For the purpose of uploading images, I am using the android volley library to send multipart requests to a server. I have written some custom code for the android **Volley** library.`HtppEntity` is used here as a class in this file, but now I am getting a warning that `HttpEntity` is deprecated. I happen to know that `HttpurlConnection` is an alternative, but I don't know how to replace it in my code?

**Here is my code**

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.util.CharsetUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by JoeyJAL on 2015/3/14.
 */
public class MultiPartRequest extends Request<String> {

    MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    HttpEntity httpentity;
    private String FILE_PART_NAME = "imageFile";

    private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
    private final File mFilePart;
    private final Map<String, String> mStringPart;

    public MultiPartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener,
                            Response.Listener<String> listener, File file,
                            Map<String, String> mStringPart) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mFilePart = file;
        this.mStringPart = mStringPart;

        entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        try {
            entity.setCharset(CharsetUtils.get("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buildMultipartEntity();
        httpentity = entity.build();
    }

    private void buildMultipartEntity() {
        entity.addPart(FILE_PART_NAME, new FileBody(mFilePart, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), mFilePart.getName()));
        if (mStringPart != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringPart.entrySet()) {
                entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return httpentity.getContentType().getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            httpentity.writeTo(bos);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {
          System.out.println("Network Response "+ new String(response.data, "UTF-8"));
            return Response.success(new String(response.data, "UTF-8"),
                    getCacheEntry());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.success(new String(response.data), getCacheEntry());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a place where others are going to take over your work for free. First, you need to show that you tried something, and share that with us.

Comment: @Rahul You only get answers/solution of your issues and problem. No-one will do your work here.

Comment: I am not telling you for doing my work just asking the replacement code.I am not able to understand that @kibzorg

Comment: ok, let me give you a demo of HttpurlConnection

Comment: i just want to have a code where as you see my example code.There my using httpentity.writeto(bos); how can i do it with httpurl connection

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000); 
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); 
conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
conn.setDoInput(true); 
conn.setDoOutput(true); 

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1)); 
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2)); 
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3)); 

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush(); 
writer.close(); 
os.close(); 

conn.connect();
```

This **getQuery(List)** will help to generate your output stream. You are uploading images so you can change that directly as output stream by replacing with getQuery() function.

```
 private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    { 
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params)
        { 
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else 
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        } 

        return result.toString();
    }
```